# I have a reader-writer shared memory in linux problem, i wrote the code in c

Tags: c, linux, reader, writer

This is the writer code:

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

struct SHM_SIZE {
    char str[512];
    int flag, readcount;
};

sem_t *resourcemutex;
int shmid, EXIT;
void sigint_handler(int sig);
struct SHM_SIZE *ptr;

int main() {
    char str[512], ss[512];
    key_t key;
    key = 1053;
    EXIT=FALSE;

    if (signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
        perror("SIGQUIT");
        exit(1);
    }

    resourcemutex = sem_open("PRAK5-3RESC", O_CREAT, 0644, 1);
    if (resourcemutex == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("unable to execute semaphore");
        sem_unlink("PRAK5-3RESC");
        exit(-1);
    }

    shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(struct SHM_SIZE), IPC_CREAT|0644);
    if (shmid < 0) {
        perror("shmget error...");
        exit(-1);
    }

    ptr = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    
    int i = 0;

    while (EXIT == FALSE) {
        printf("Masukkan Kata/kalimat : ");
        scanf("%[^\n]", ss); getchar(); //The input to send to resourcemutex
        fflush(stdin);
        sem_wait(resourcemutex);
        strcpy(ptr->str, ss);
        ptr->flag = 1;
        sem_post(resourcemutex);
        i++;

        }
    sem_close(resourcemutex);

    return 0;
}

void sigint_handler(int sig) {
    EXIT = TRUE;  //to close resourcemutex
    
    sem_close(resourcemutex);
    sem_unlink("PRAK5-3RESC");
}
```

This is the reader code:

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

struct SHM_SIZE {
    char str[512];
    int flag, readcount;
};

int EXIT;
int shmid;
sem_t *readermutex, *resourcemutex;
struct SHM_SIZE *ptr;

void sigint_handler(int sig);

int main() {
    int i, j;
    char ss[512], str[512];
    key_t key;
    EXIT=FALSE;

    if (signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
        perror("SIGQUIT");
        exit(1);
    }

    readermutex = sem_open("PRAK5-3READ", O_CREAT, 0644, 1);
    if (readermutex == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("unable to create semaphore");
        sem_unlink("PRAK5-3READ");
        exit(-1);
    }

    resourcemutex = sem_open("PRAK5-3RESC", O_CREAT, 0644, 1);
    if (resourcemutex == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("unable to create semaphore");
        sem_unlink("PRAK5-3READ");
        exit(-1);
    }

    shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(struct SHM_SIZE), IPC_CREAT | 0644);
    if (shmid < 0) {
        perror("failure in shmget");
        exit(-1);
    }

    ptr = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    while (EXIT == FALSE) {
        sem_wait(resourcemutex);
        if (ptr->flag == 0) {
            usleep(1000);
            continue;
        } else {
            printf("Reading %s\n", ptr->str);
            ptr->flag = 0;
        }
        sem_post(resourcemutex);
    }
    return 0;
}

void sigint_handler(int sig) { //close the mutex
    EXIT = TRUE;

    sem_close(readermutex);
    sem_close(resourcemutex);
    sem_unlink("PRAK5-3READ");//close the mutex
    sem_unlink("PRAK5-3RESC");//close the mutex
    shmdt(ptr);
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    exit(0);
}
```

To explain more further, the code have to be like this:
Terminal 1 (writer):
Please enter the words and the sentence: whatever i put in here should print to resourcemutex, the reader code should read the resourcemutex and print it to readermutex so that it can be printed to the linux screen.

Terminal 2 (reader):
Whatever i write in terminal 1 should be printed here

It's like a shared memory using mutex, but idk it's not working.

The result:
[My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Espt3.png)

i don't know why it can't be printed in the reader and there is a problem when u want to execute the write program its always failed and return some segmentation fault (core) or smth

Comment: In the reader, you loop on `sem_wait`. But, if the flag is 0, you do a `usleep` but do _not_ do a `sem_post` because of the `continue`. Try removing the `continue`.

Comment: I already erase the `continue` but still didn't work

Comment: Some suggestions. There should be two semaphores. One for mutex for accessing shared memory and the other for signalling the reader that data is available in the shared memory. The writer should be run first and reader after that. The writer should initialize the mutex semaphore as 1. Initially there is no data; so signalling semaphore should be zero. After writing, the signalling semaphore should be made 1 by the writer. The reader should not give initial value to semaphores, just sem_open with two parameters. The reader should block for data, doing a sem_wait on signalling semaphore.